# Append format options and events to column model while column model is binding dynamically in jqgrid

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, jqgrid, inline-editing

In MvcJQGrid, I have to bind column dynamically that is working fine, but I have to do inline editing with edit button at each row.
When I'm passing column model at client side like this...

```
colModel:[
                { index: 'Id', name: 'Id', align: 'center', 'hidden': true, editable: false },
                { index: 'Name', name: 'Name', align: 'center', editable: true },
                { index: 'Value', name: 'Value', align: 'center', editable: true },
                {
                    name: 'Id', index: 'Id', width: 55, align: 'center', sortable: false, formatter: 'actions',
                    formatoptions: {
                        keys: true, // we want use [Enter] key to save the row and [Esc] to cancel editing.
                        onEdit: function (rowid) {
                            alert("in onEdit: rowid=" + rowid + "\nWe don't need return anything");
                        },
                        onSuccess: function (jqXHR) {
                            var d = $('#dataList').jqGrid('getCell', rowid, 'Id');
                            alert("in onSuccess used only for remote editing:" +
                                  "\nresponseText=" + jqXHR.responseText +
                                  "\n\nWe can verify the server response and return false in case of" +
                                  " error response. return true confirm that the response is successful");
                            return true;
                        },
                        onError: function (rowid, jqXHR, textStatus) {
                            alert("in onError used only for remote editing:" +
                                  "\nresponseText=" + jqXHR.responseText +
                                  "\nstatus=" + jqXHR.status +
                                  "\nstatusText" + jqXHR.statusText +
                                  "\n\nWe don't need return anything");
                        },
                        afterSave: function (rowid) {
                            debugger;
                            var d = $('#dataList').jqGrid('getCell', rowid, 'Id');
                            alert("in afterSave (Submit): rowid=" + rowid + d);
                        },
                        afterRestore: function (rowid) {
                            alert("in afterRestore (Cancel): rowid=" + rowid + "\nWe don't need return anything");
                        },
                        delOptions: {
                            onclickSubmit: function (rp_ge, rowid) {
                                debugger;
                                var selRowId = $('#dataList').jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selrow');
                                var celValue = $('#dataList').jqGrid('getCell', selRowId, 'Id');
                                debugger;

                                alert("The row with rowid=" + rowid + " will be deleted Guid: " + (rowid.Id));

                                rp_ge.processing = true;

                                $("#dataList").delRowData(rowid);
                                $("#delmod" + grid[0].id).hide();

                                if (grid[0].p.lastpage > 1) {
                                    // reload grid to make the row from the next page visable.
                                    // TODO: deleting the last row from the last page which number is higher as 1
                                    grid.trigger("reloadGrid", [{ page: grid[0].p.page }]);
                                }
                                return true;
                            },
                            processing: true // !!! the most important step for the "local" editing
                            //     skip ajax request to the server
                        }
                    }
                }
            ],
```

then it is working , but column will be bind on run time and last elemet of column model will provide at client side

on getting column model from server i am getting

```
[Object { Index="Id", Name="Id", Align="center"}, Object { Index="Name", Name="Name", Align="center"}, Object { Index="Value", Name="Value", Align="center"}]
```

In that case how to bind column model so that after getting column model like above I can append

```
{
                    name: 'Id', index: 'Id', width: 55, align: 'center', sortable: false, formatter: 'actions',
                    formatoptions: {
                        keys: true, // we want use [Enter] key to save the row and [Esc] to cancel editing.
                        onEdit: function (rowid) {
                            alert("in onEdit: rowid=" + rowid + "\nWe don't need return anything");
                        },
                        onSuccess: function (jqXHR) {
                            var d = $('#dataList').jqGrid('getCell', rowid, 'Id');
                            alert("in onSuccess used only for remote editing:" +
                                  "\nresponseText=" + jqXHR.responseText +
                                  "\n\nWe can verify the server response and return false in case of" +
                                  " error response. return true confirm that the response is successful");
                            return true;
                        },
                        onError: function (rowid, jqXHR, textStatus) {
                            alert("in onError used only for remote editing:" +
                                  "\nresponseText=" + jqXHR.responseText +
                                  "\nstatus=" + jqXHR.status +
                                  "\nstatusText" + jqXHR.statusText +
                                  "\n\nWe don't need return anything");
                        },
                        afterSave: function (rowid) {
                            debugger;
                            var d = $('#dataList').jqGrid('getCell', rowid, 'Id');
                            alert("in afterSave (Submit): rowid=" + rowid + d);
                        },
                        afterRestore: function (rowid) {
                            alert("in afterRestore (Cancel): rowid=" + rowid + "\nWe don't need return anything");
                        },
                        delOptions: {
                            onclickSubmit: function (rp_ge, rowid) {
                                debugger;
                                var selRowId = $('#dataList').jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selrow');
                                var celValue = $('#dataList').jqGrid('getCell', selRowId, 'Id');
                                debugger;

                                alert("The row with rowid=" + rowid + " will be deleted Guid: " + (rowid.Id));

                                rp_ge.processing = true;

                                $("#dataList").delRowData(rowid);
                                $("#delmod" + grid[0].id).hide();

                                if (grid[0].p.lastpage > 1) {
                                    // reload grid to make the row from the next page visable.
                                    // TODO: deleting the last row from the last page which number is higher as 1
                                    grid.trigger("reloadGrid", [{ page: grid[0].p.page }]);
                                }
                                return true;
                            },
                            processing: true // !!! the most important step for the "local" editing
                            //     skip ajax request to the server
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Comment: first of all you can't specify `name: 'Id'` **twice** (you can't use the same value of `name` property for different columns in `colModel`). You have to change the value of `name` property for the column which have `formatter: "actions"`.

Comment: ok.. but first part is working fine, I'll avoid this to do, kindly tell me how to merge last 2 parts of code. As column is getting dynamically in json that is part 2 and for inline editing setting i have to pass code part 3 in column model.

Comment: code for getting column model is
$.ajax(
             {
                 async: false,
                 type: "POST",
                 url: url + editurl,
                 dataType: "json",
                 contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                 cache: false,
                 sync: false,
                 success: function (result) {
                     debugger;
                     columnNames = result.columNames;
                     colModel = result.columnModel;
                 }
             });

and then this colModel is passed to jqgrid as
colModel:colModel

Comment: sorry, but I don't understand your question. Do you have problems with *loading of data* or with *editing* of data? What is **dynamical**? The names of the columns? Which *binding* problem you have? Is the value of `Id` column **unique**?

Comment: yes Id is unique,But other column name "Name", "Value" can change at run time, that I m getting using ajax call

Comment: Is the number of columns are the same (two visible columns)?

Comment: column model is binding dynamically but 3rd part of code is static taht I have to pass to column model that is getting after ajaxcall

Comment: NO, column no is not fixed there may be many column like Value, Value1, Value2,,, etc
That's why i m passing model dynamically.

Comment: Which part of the code you mean under "3rd part"?

Comment: In my above question code is written into 3 parts
1st part: working fine but contain static column
2nd part: result getting from ajax hit for column model
3rd part: contains event for edit delete selected row

Comment: code with dynamic column binding is

jQuery("#dataList").jqGrid({
                url: grdurl,datatype: "json",colNames: columnNames,colModel: colModel,autowidth: true,width: 'auto',height: 'auto',rowNum: 10,rowList: [10, 20, 30],scrolling: true,shrinktofit: true,pager: '#pager',sortname: 'Name',rownumbers: false,rownumWidth: 30,viewrecords: true,sortorder: "desc",multiselect: false,imgpath: gridimgpath});

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand you. If you what that somebody help you should should answer on the questions to your text. Moreover you should specify more clear which kind of `colModel` you want to support. You can't load all common code of `colModel` (which could contains function etc) inside of server. JSON can't be used to transfer small subset of data types only. If you want to get an answer you should **modify the text of your question** and append all important information in the text. Posting code in comments isn't productive.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42843/discussion-between-swati-sinha-and-oleg)